# How to use article the

Tags: articles, definite-article, proper-nouns

I know "Cambridge University" is correct but why don't we use "the Cambridge University".

Comment: There is no single rule for using article _the_. It's usually idiomatic and when it's not you can't tell.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Please read the label. Try English Language Learners, where questions on the use of articles in English must have been asked dozens of times.

Comment: There is the alternative construct **The University of Cambridge**

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, it *isn't* correct; the [website](https://www.cam.ac.uk/) shows that **University of Cambridge** is the official name, and we would refer to *the University of Cambridge*. It is often called *Cambridge University* in everyday conversation. However some universities do have **X University** as their official name, [see](https://www.hw.ac.uk/), in which case an article is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definite article "the" before a proper noun is unnecessary, since you're generally only referring to *one* such entity. It would be the equivalent of saying "I'm going to *the* London tomorrow."

However, if you're using the proper noun as a *qualifier* for something else, then by all means it should be preceded by the article: "the Cambridge University sports program."

Comment: Interestingly, "I'm on a course at The Open University" and "I'm on an Open University course" are both correct.